# Empty does not complete observable in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

```
import { of, timer, EMPTY } from "rxjs"
import { concatMap, takeUntil, tap, switchMapTo } from "rxjs/operators"


of(1,2,3,4,5).pipe(
concatMap(val => {
    return timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        takeUntil(timer(3000)),
        switchMapTo(EMPTY)
    )
})
).subscribe()
```

This code takes 15 seconds to run. I thought when EMPTY is returned it marks the timer observable as complete and stops emitting. And that concatMap should take in the next value immediately. So my expectations is that it should take 0 seconds.

EDIT:

My specific example has to do with polling requests and bail out if I get a bad response. Essentially overriding the specified takeUntil.

```
of([header1, header2, ...]).pipe(
concatMap(header => {
    const response1 = axios.get(...use header here)
    return timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        takeUntil(timer(3000)),
        switchMapTo(of(makeRequest(...based on response1))),
        // here i want to filter the values that the second request 
        // gets and make sure they are OK.
        // if they are not okay i want to get a new header, which 
        // leads 
        // to new response1 which leads to new makeRequests
        // so i want to essentially bail out before takeUntil if i get 
        //a bad response.
    )
}),
).subscribe().
```

EDIT 2

I solved it using both takeUntil and takeWhile, the one that gets triggered will override the other!

Comment: @JonathanStellwag I updated the code and text, sorry for the wrong code

Comment: According to the documentation, EMPTY `Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits a complete notification.` So it sounds like it would be creating and completing a new Observable, not completing the source Observable.

Comment: @DeborahK I'm not sure I understand that definition based on this code: of(1).pipe(switchMapTo(EMPTY)).subscribe() . This will send a complete notification to the "source" and complete immediately

Answer (score 2):

These two snippets of code are roughly the same.

```
of(1,2,3,4,5).pipe(
  concatMap(_ =>
    timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      takeUntil(timer(3000)),
      switchMapTo(EMPTY)
    )
  )
).subscribe()
```

```
of(1,2,3,4,5).pipe(
  concatMap(_ =>
    timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      takeUntil(timer(3000)),
      filter(_ => false)
    )
  )
).subscribe()
```

`switchMapTo(EMPTY)`: any values that hit this point of the pipeline are ignored and turned into a stream that completes immediately.

When inside of a `switchMap`, completing doesn't cause the `switchMap` to complete. It'll just wait for another value to map and a new stream to subscribe to.

What are you trying to accomplish?

---

#### Update: About `timer`

Most of the time, these will be the same:

```
timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  takeUntil(timer(2100))
).subscribe(console.log);

timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  takeUntil(timer(3000))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

`timer(3000)`'s first emission and `timer(1,1000)`'s fourth emission technically land on the same millisecond. Because JavaScript doesn't make guarantees on how precisely these delays are managed, some setups will take the 4th value, and some (most) will not.

It's even possible that what happens depends on how busy the event loop currently is.

If your actual code uses that setup, I would recommend using `take(number)` instead.

```
timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  take(3)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Using code like this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { of, timer, EMPTY } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, takeUntil, tap, switchMapTo } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  constructor() {
    of(1, 2, 3)
      .pipe(
        tap(x => console.log('Emitted value: ', x)),
        switchMapTo(EMPTY))
      .subscribe({
        next: x => console.log('Result: ', x),
        error: err => console.log('Error: ' , err),
        complete: () => console.log('Complete')
      });
  }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
Emitted value: 1
Emitted value: 2
Emitted value: 3
Complete
```

So the `switchMapTo(EMPTY)` does not appear to complete the source stream.

Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-deborahk

What are you trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Im trying to force the timer observable to complete and override the takeUntil. Right now takeUntil is the only way to make the stream complete.

Comment: You could consider adding an "action stream" with a Subject/BehaviorSubject and combine that with the source stream. Then emit into that action stream when you want to override the `takeUntil`

Comment: That sounds good. I updated my question with what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: If you could do a *working* stackblitz that illustrates your example, I'll take a look.